# Apache HTTPD 2.4.x: How to "direct" users to a a custom error page if certain characters are present in the URL/URI?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

so I have this apache config where I'm trying to "rewrite" users to a custom error page but it's not working. I entered `http://localhost/index.html/ddgdg%:sdsdfs` in the browser and I didn't get my error page.

I can view the custom error page by directly entering its URL in the browser (`http://localhost/my-error.html`).

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

---

**my full httpd.conf**: [link to httpd.conf](https://pastebin.com/raw/f1fsJBS1)

---

**my changes to the default httpd.conf** (I also had to uncomment the LoadModule for mod_rewrite.so)

```
RewriteEngine On
LogLevel alert rewrite:info
#if invalid characters are present in the URI, display 404 page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/.+[:%].+  
RewriteRule "^/$" "http://%{SERVER_NAME}/my-error.html" [L,R=301]
```

---

**contents of custom error page**

```
$ cat /Library/WebServer/Documents/my-error.html 
<html><body><h1>404 error here</h1></body></html>
```

---

**apache version**

```
$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 22 2019 20:20:11
```

**edit1:** Running macOS Mojave at the moment but will setup an Ubuntu VM in awhile.

Comment: "I didn't get my error page." - What response did you get? A "400 Bad Request"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different issues going on here...

> ```
> http://localhost/index.html/ddgdg%:sdsdfs
> ```

You've not actually stated what response you are getting, just what is *not happening*. However, due to the stray `%` (not preceding a hexadecimal encoded octet), this URL is strictly invalid and I would expect Apache to respond with a `400 Bad Request`. The only way to override this is to create a custom 400 error document in which you check the requested URL and customise the response. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /my-error.html
```

If it wasn't for the stray `%` you should be able to catch this request using mod_rewrite and redirect accordingly. However, your `RewriteRule` is checking for an empty URL-path (ie. `"^/$"`), whereas the requested URL in your example is far from empty (ie. `/index.html/ddgdg%:sdsdfs`) - so the `RewriteRule` directive will never match your example URL. To check for `%` or `:` anywhere in the URL-path and redirect you could do something like the following:

```
# Checks for a "%" or ":" in the URL-path
RewriteRule [%:] /my-error.html [L,R=302]
```

But note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (as well as the `REQUEST_URI` server variable) is already %-decoded, so this will only match URLs where special characters have been doubly encoded (rare). (As noted above, an otherwise stray `%` will likely generate a 400 response *before* mod_rewrite is able to process the request.)

I would also question why you are wanting to "redirect" to your custom error document (ie. `my-error.html`) and not serve it directly? Redirecting has a number of disadvantages: 3xx response sent to the client, lost information regarding the URL that caused the error, doubling the requests to your server, etc.

You could *internally rewrite* the request to `/my-error.html`, instead of redirecting, by simply removing the `R` flag. For example:

```
RewriteRule [%:] /my-error.html [L]
```

But, unless you manually set the HTTP status in `my-error.html` then the user will see a `200 OK` response - which is not desirable.

OR (preferably) create a custom 404 (which looks like what you are trying to do) and trigger that instead. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /my-error.html

RewriteRule [%:] - [R=404]
```

Apache then sets the "404 Not Found" HTTP response status.

However, you probably don't need to use mod_rewrite at all here. In your example URL, everything after `index.html` in the URL-path, namely `/ddgdg%:sdsdfs`, is *additional pathname information* (aka path-info / `PATH_INFO`). By default, the handler that processes text/html responses does not permit path-info and will implicitly trigger a 404 (if it wasn't for the stray `%` - as discussed above), calling your custom `ErrorDocument` (if defined). So, the `RewriteRule` directive in the last example can simply be removed, since Apache will trigger a 404 anyway (unless you override this behaviour with `AcceptPathInfo`).